# Selecting a "null" value using mat-option with Angular 7 Reactive Forms Not Working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to default select an option which contains a "null" [value] in a mat-select.  The problem is, it does not select the option with the "null" [value] when the html is displayed.  I am using Angular 7 Reactive Forms with Angular Material 7.  Here is what I have -

Html:

```html
<mat-select placeholder="User" formControlName="userId">
  <mat-option [value]="null">None</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.userId">
      {{ user.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Component.ts:

this.userId.setValue(null);

The line above assumes that I have already instantiated my formGroup with one of the formControls being called "userId" and "this.userId" is a property of my component which references "this.userForm.get('userId')".

So when I set the formControl value of "userId" to null nothing is ever selected in the html.  I was under the impression that you can have a "null" value as one of the options of a mat-select, Am I wrong?  If not, any suggestions on what I can do to get this to work the way I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not set the null because you have integer property (user.userId), The sample code should be work.

**Template Code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="patientCategory">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-select placeholder="Category" formControlName="patientCategory">
            <mat-option [value]="0">None</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let category of patientCategories" [value]="category.id">
                {{category.name}} - {{category.description}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <p>{{patientCategory.get('patientCategory').value | json}}</p>
</form>
```

**Componet Code**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Basic table
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  patientCategory: FormGroup;

  patientCategories = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'name 1',
    description: 'description 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name 2',
    description: 'description 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name 3',
    description: 'description 3'
  }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.patientCategory = this.fb.group({
      patientCategory: [null, Validators.required]
    });

    //const toSelect = this.patientCategories.find(c => c.id == 3);
    this.patientCategory.get('patientCategory').setValue(0);
  }
}
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-default-value-mat-select)**

Comment: Thanks, I had to go this way and set the value to 0.  Added a little headache on the backend, but it did the trick thanks.

Comment: To avoid changing the backend, you can do this (this is with template forms):
`[ngModel]="value ?? 0"
(ngModelChange)="value = $event || null"`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try pushing the default null values as first option of 'users' array.

```
this.users.unshift({
  userId: null,
  name: 'select'
});
```

**Template:**

```
<mat-select placeholder="User" formControlName="userId">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.userId">
      {{ user.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, but that didn't seem to work.  The form value of the formcontrol is "null" but the mat-select still doesn't select it.